# Is there a macro/extension to set all web projects in Visual Studio to "Don't Open a Page"?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Occasionally, I'm debugging a problem that occurs across several of our back-end web services, and I have them all setup as startup projects; when I hit F5, they all launch new tabs in whatever browser I have set to default at the time -- it would be useful to me to be able to click a button, and have all of the `Project > Properties > Web > Start Action` settings set to "don't open a page."  Anyone know of a macro or extension that might be able to help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote most of the solution for you, except I wasn't sure how to check if a Project is an ASP.NET project or not. One way to do it could be to check whether `Project.ExtenderNames` contains the string "WebApplication", but I'm not sure that's the best solution.

```
Sub ChangeAllWebProjectsStartActionToDontStartWebPage()
    Dim project As EnvDTE.Project
    If DTE.Solution.IsOpen Then
        For Each project In DTE.Solution.Projects
            NavProj(project)
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Sub NavProj(ByVal project As Project)
    Dim outputPathProperty As EnvDTE.Property
    Dim outputPath As String

    If Not (project.ConfigurationManager Is Nothing) Then
        ' It's a project!
        Dim extenderNames As String()
        extenderNames = project.ExtenderNames
        If (Array.IndexOf(extenderNames, "WebApplication") >= 0) Then
            project.Properties.Item("WebApplication.DebugStartAction").Value = 4 ' WebStartAction.NoStartPage
        End If
    Else
        NavProjItems(project.ProjectItems)
    End If
End Sub

Sub NavProjItems(ByVal projItems As ProjectItems)
    Dim projectItem As EnvDTE.ProjectItem

    If Not (projItems Is Nothing) Then
        For Each projectItem In projItems
            If Not (projectItem.SubProject Is Nothing) Then
                ' Recurse, can be an Enterprise project in 
                ' Visual Studio .NET 2002/2003 or a solution folder in VS 2005+
                NavProj(projectItem.SubProject)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

This is based on the WebStartAction which is defined as:

```
    enum WebStartAction
    {
        CurrentPage = 0,
        SpecificPage = 1,
        Program = 2,
        URL = 3,
        NoStartPage = 4
    }
```

Comment: This got me on the right track, but I ran into issues with solution folders.  I've re-learned enough VB to modify things, and blatantly copy-pasted from the internet the majority of it.  Edited the answer to include my results.